# Why does the application can run faster when the number of processes is greater than the total number of threads in CPU in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

Why does the application run faster by using more processes when the number of processes is greater than the total number of threads in CPU in python?
Here is the code

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def wait():
    time.sleep(1)

start = time.time()

#create the process pool
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=40) as executor:
    future = []
    for _ in range(400):
        future.append(executor.submit(wait))
    start2 = time.time()
    future_res = []
    for i,v in enumerate(future):
        future_res.append(v.result())
    print(time.time()-start)
    print(time.time()-start2)
```

its output is:

```
10.364367246627808
9.99793791770935
```

Does it mean that a application will run faster and faster if I use more and more processes?

Comment: Because the vast amount of time of your program is CPU-idle since you have `sleep(1)`? At any one time, you don't have 40 processes fighting for the CPU

Comment: Is the reason that the application is an IO intensive application rather than a compute-intensive one?

Comment: @roganjosh yes.I think so too

Comment: Kinda, if you wanna think about it in terms of `sleep()` being a process waiting for a callback or something, but it's really just dead time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given `wait` function doesn't consume any interesting amount of CPU cycles; it only interacts with the scheduler. It is hardly surprising that higher concurrency levels would let lots of overlapping sleep's complete quicker. Here you chose `num_tasks = 400`. For large values, your completion time will tend toward the ratio of `num_tasks / max_workers`. This is absolutely not the behavior that a CPU-bound workload would experience.

If you have a different workload in mind as your "real" problem, ask about it in a separate question, and describe whether it is largely CPU-, I/O-, or network-bound.